# Feature names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different! when using LIME package to explain xgboost model in R

Tags: r, xgboost, lime

I'm trying to use LIME to explain a binary classification model that I've trained using XGboost.  I run into an error when calling the `explain()` function from LIME, which implies that I have columns that aren't matching in my model (or explainer) and the new data I'm trying to explain predictions for.

This [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lime/vignettes/Understanding_lime.html) for LIME does demonstrate a version with xgboost, however it's a text problem which is a little different to my tabular data. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296577/r-explain-on-lime-feature-names-stored-in-object-and-newdata-are-different) seems to be encountering the same error, but also for a document term matrix, which seems to obscure the solution for my case.   I've worked up a minimal example with `mtcars` which produced exactly the same errors I get in my own larger dataset.

```
library(pacman)
p_load(tidyverse)
p_load(xgboost)
p_load(Matrix)
p_load(lime)

### Prepare data with partition
df <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column()
length <- df %>% nrow()
df_train <- df %>% select(-rowname) %>% head((length-10))
df_test <- df %>% select(-rowname) %>% tail(10)

### Transform data into matrix objects for XGboost
train <- list(sparse.model.matrix(~., data = df_train %>% select(-vs)), (df_train$vs %>% as.factor()))
names(train) <- c("data", "label")
test <- list(sparse.model.matrix(~., data = df_test %>% select(-vs)), (df_test$vs %>% as.factor()))
names(test) <- c("data", "label")
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = train$data, label=train$label)
dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(data = test$data, label=test$label)


### Train model
watchlist <- list(train=dtrain, test=dtest)
mod_xgb_tree <- xgb.train(data = dtrain,  booster = "gbtree", eta = .1, nrounds = 15, watchlist = watchlist)

### Check prediction works
output <- predict(mod_xgb_tree, test$data) %>% tibble()

### attempt lime explanation
explainer <- df_train %>% select(-vs) %>% lime(model = mod_xgb_tree)  ### works, no error or warning
explanation <- df_test %>% select(-vs) %>% explain(explainer, n_features = 4) ### error, Features stored names in `object` and `newdata` are different!

names_test <- test$data@Dimnames[[2]]  ### 10 names
names_mod <- mod_xgb_tree$feature_names ### 11 names
names_explainer <- explainer$feature_type %>% enframe() %>% pull(name) ### 11 names


### see whether pre-processing helps
my_preprocess <- function(df){
  data <- df %>% select(-vs)
  label <- df$vs

  test <<- list(sparse.model.matrix( ~ ., data = data), label)
  names(test) <<- c("data", "label")

  dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(data = test$data, label=test$label)
  dtest
}

explanation <- df_test %>% explain(explainer, preprocess = my_preprocess(), n_features = 4) ### Error in feature_distribution[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

### check that the preprocessing is working ok
dtest_check <- df_test %>% my_preprocess()
output_check <- predict(mod_xgb_tree, dtest_check)
```

I assume that because the `explainer` only has the names of the original predictor columns, where test data in its transformed state also has an `(Intercept)` column, this is causing the problem.  I just haven't figured out a neat way of preventing this occurring.  Any help would be much appreciated. I assume there must be a neat solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but the columns weren't in alphabetical order.  To fix this, I matched the order of the column names in the df_test to df_train so that the column names were in the same order.

Create list of df_test column numbers in same order as df_train:

```
    idx<- match(colnames(df_train), colnames(df_test))
```

Create new df_test file using this column order:

```
    df_test_match <- df_test[,idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at this page (https://rdrr.io/cran/xgboost/src/R/xgb.Booster.R), you will see that some R users are likely to get the following error message: "Feature names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different!".

Here is the code from this page related to the error message:

```
predict.xgb.Booster <- function(object, newdata, missing = NA, outputmargin = FALSE, ntreelimit = NULL,predleaf = FALSE, predcontrib = FALSE, approxcontrib = FALSE, predinteraction = FALSE,reshape = FALSE, ...)

object <- xgb.Booster.complete(object, saveraw = FALSE)
      if (!inherits(newdata, "xgb.DMatrix"))
        newdata <- xgb.DMatrix(newdata, missing = missing)
      if (!is.null(object[["feature_names"]]) &&
          !is.null(colnames(newdata)) &&
          !identical(object[["feature_names"]], colnames(newdata)))
        stop("Feature names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different!")
```

`identical(object[["feature_names"]], colnames(newdata))` => If the column names of `object` (i.e. your model based on your training set) are not identical to the column names of `newdata` (i.e. your test set), you will get the error message.

For more details:

```
train_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(training %>% select(-target)), label = training$target, missing = NaN)
object <- xgb.train(data=train_matrix, params=..., nthread=2, nrounds=..., prediction = T)
newdata <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(test %>% select(-target)), missing = NaN)
```

While setting by yourself `object` and `newdata` with your data thanks to the code above, you can probably fix this issue by looking at the differences between `object[["feature_names"]]` and `colnames(newdata)`. Probably some columns that don't appear in the same order or something.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your new dataset,

```
   colnames(test)<- make.names(colnames(test))

   newdataset<- test %>% mutate_all(as.numeric)

   newdataset<- as.matrix(newdataset)

   nwtest<-xgb.DMatrix(newdataset)
```

Comment: I have trouble with the first line.. Which object shoudld I call `colnames()<-` on? If I do on the dataframe `df_test` I get a bunch of NAs for colnames, and can't proceed.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the (Intercept) column showing up, you need to change your code slightly when creating the sparse matrix for your test data.
Change the line:

```
test <- list(sparse.model.matrix( ~ ., data = data), label)
```

to:

```
test <- list(sparse.model.matrix( ~ .-1, data = data), label)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I gave this a try, didn't seem to work though.